# TypeScript's type inference for Promise.all fails in Vue on WebStorm2023.1

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, webstorm

In this code, everything works fine in the ts file, and the variable first is correctly resolved to the string type.

But when I tried to use it under Vue3's Composition API, all types were merged. This causes me to have to force the type to be specified.

What do I have to do to get it recognized correctly even in Vue files?

TypeScript version: 5.0.4

```js
// in .ts file
// type () => Promise<string>
const fun1 = () => Promise.resolve('A')
const fun2 = () => Promise.resolve([1])
const b = 1 + 1 === 2
Promise.all([fun1(), b ? fun2() : null]).then((res) => {
  // res type [string, number[] | null]

  // string
  const first = res[0]

  // number[]|null
  const second = res[1]
})
```

```js
// in .vue file
<script setup>
// type () => Promise<Awaited<string>>
const fun1 = () => Promise.resolve('A')
const fun2 = () => Promise.resolve([1])
const b = 1 + 1 === 2
Promise.all([fun1(), b ? fun2() : null]).then((res) => {
  // res type Awaited<string | number[] | null>[]

  // type string|number[]|null
  const first = res[0]

  // type string|number[]|null
  const second = res[1]
})
</script>
```

Comment: This is not a general problem with .vue files. Most likely, your IDE plugin for .vue files is using an old typescript version. What IDE and plugin are you using?

Comment: @MoritzRingler I'm having problems with WebStorm 2023.1.3, I've tested vscode without this problem. I mistakenly thought this was a vue issue, so it looks like I need to go to Jetbrains and ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be fixed in WebStorm 2023.2, you can try this in the EAP version that is generally available right now.
Here's a link to the related announcement https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2023/05/webstorm-2023-2-eap2/

I also personally tested it in the latest EAP Version and it seems to work in my opinion.
[image]